# CD Reader is producing corrupt files

Tags: audio, file-corruption, cd

I have a few CDs and DVDs with music on them that I want to transfer and store on my Windows computer. Some of the disks are being read fine however some of them are being read with the audio files being corrupt. For example, a lot of the mp3 files will contain 2 songs with one song ending and another starting in the middle of the same file and then abruptly cutting off at the end of the file only to continue in the next music file. When trying to verify the music files' integrity, there is a reported MPEG stream error and the reported length is inaccurate. Other files like .jpg images are also corrupt and can't be opened with any software.

The real issue is that I'm certain the issue isn't with the original data on the CD since other devices like my car stereo are reading the CDs and playing music just fine with none of the above issues.

The CD reader I have connected to my computer is really cheap (£13 from Amazon) so I don't know if the CD reader is the issue or if it's something with my computer.

Comment: The issue is very likely copy protection.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the CD drive lens?